# php function to select data from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, function

I use the following function to select data from a MYSQL database:

```
if (!function_exists('select_array_where')) {
function select_array_where($what, $from, $where){

$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "db");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
{
    echo "<br>Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error . "<br>";
}

$result = $mysqli ->query("SELECT $what FROM $from WHERE $where");

$array = Array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $array[] =  $row[$what];
}

print_r ($array);
return $array;
}
}
```

Which works perfectly well if $what has only one value:

```
$name_array = Array();
    $name_array =& select_array_where("name", "inter_company", "transaction_type='interest'");
```

But it does not work in the following case:

```
  $company_int_array = array();
  $company_int_array =& select_array_where("amount, perc", "inter_company", "transaction_type='interest'");
```

I've a feeling it relates to punctuation and have tried movies comma's, " and ' around, in and out but nothing helps...

Anyone an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Anyway, could you please copy the error message you get? Adding a try..catch would be a good idea also

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: 'amount', 'perc'

Comment: `"amount, perc",` these would need to be separated `"amount", "perc",`

Comment: Doesn't work, believe that I can only have three things between " and " because of the way the function is defined ($what, $from and $where)

Comment: Simplest would be to change `$array[] =  $row[$what];` to a simple `$array[] =  $row;`, where you don't specify the `$what` key(s).

Comment: Try to use ticks `\`` around each word the `amount, perc` with your existing quotes, or wrapping the whole thing.

Comment: Or more complex you could pass an array - `select_array_where(array("amount, perc"), "inter_company", "transaction_type='interest'");`. Then you can use `is_array()` to check the `$what` value before building your query, and use `implode()`, plus the simple suggestion above for the return.

Comment: great, that's it! not sure to understand why though... would you mind explaining? (I mean the one without specifying the $what keys

Comment: @Sean I have a feeling your suggestion could work.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have written out an answer, and am working on the edit to show how to use `array()` and your suggestion of backticks.

Comment: @Sean That's great Sean. I hope it works for the OP. I'll stay in the question, which I like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that

```
 $array[] = $row[$what];
```

is evaluating to

```
 $array[] = $row['amount perc'];
```

which is invalid as you don't have a single column named `'amount, perc'`.

The simplest solution is to change to

```
$array[] = $row;
```

which is equivalent to doing

```
$array[] = array('amount'=>$row['amount'], 'perc'=>$row['perc']);
```

but does not require you to know/specify the actual column names/keys

Comment: Luvin' that *green* ;-) Good job Sean.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you have to replace the line:
     $array[] =  $row[$what];
With the lines:

```
 $Whatsarr = explode ($what);
 Foreach ($what as $col)
 $aux[$col] = $row [$col];
 $array []= $aux:
```

Comment: How does this address the OP's issue on this line - `array[] =  $row[$what];`? That would evaluate to `array[] =  $row['amount', 'perc'];`, which is invalid.

Comment: Correct, this doesn't help

Comment: I have fixed my answer

Comment: Your edit is closer, but this would create a new array element for each column, each time. So if you had 2 columns and 3 rows in the database, then instead of 3 array elements with 2 key/value pairs in each, you will have 6 array elements with 1 key/value pair in each.

Comment: Did you execute it to know this?! Notice that the Foreach loop includes only the first line after it